# mysql: most efficient method to store parameters with unknown type (string/int) to the db

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a messaging system that contains default templates. for example:

`you won X coins`

`friend X wants to share the url Y with you`

so the number of parameters varies in each message/template type.

I thought of 4 types of solutions to resolve the issue:

1. creating a parameters table and represent each parameter type as a string.
   the problem here that user_ids will be represented as strings so probably joins will be slower. e
2. creating a parameters table that each row contains the following a boolean that tells if the parameter is an int or a string, and 2 other columns one type text and the other type INT. so here we're kind of wasting space because whenever we use an int parameter the row contains an unused string cell.
3. not to create a parameters table at all, each notification contains a parameters string that contains each needed parameter with a seperator `;`. this one may be the slowest solution.
4. creating two different tables for each time of parameters: notification_param_int and notification_param_string and a table that contains each parameter in the notification to the relevant table. this solution may be slower then solution 2 because i need to check from which table to fetch the information first.

are there any other options I did not think about ?
if I don't care about space, only about speed, which method should I take ?

I'm not a MySQL expert so the conclusion of each method may be wrong.

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, when having a open-ended property table as you describe, you'll discover that some of the properties are more important (either they need to always be there, or they need to be fast).  In that case, promote those to fields in the main record.

I could imagine UID being that.  It would be a problem later if you needed to have a list of UID (friends), but then you could also promote friends to its own table.

In your case, I'd just opt for #1 or #2 and think about promoting important properties if the need arises.